# wpf 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw an exception. Specified element is already the logical child of another element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application for playing a video and then navigating to another screen. The application plays the video first, and navigating to page2.xaml and again navigating to videos page I get the below exception.

My xaml looks like this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="MainGrid">     
  <ContentControl x:Name="cntctrl" Content="{Binding VlcObject}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

The VlcObject is an instance of Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl and I have noticed that VlcObject.MediaPlayer is being disposed on navigating to the second page. So on navigating to videos page, I am creating a new instance of VlcObject.
My ViewModel looks like this:

```
    private Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl _vlcObject = null;
    public Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl VlcObject
    {
        get { return _vlcObject; }
        set { Set(nameof(VlcObject), ref _vlcObject, value); }
    }
    private void InitialiseVLC()
    {
        if (VlcObject == null || VlcObject.MediaPlayer.IsDisposed)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                VlcObject = null;
                VlcObject = new Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl();
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.Opening += MediaPlayer_Opening;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.EndReached += MediaPlayer_EndReached;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.EncounteredError += MediaPlayer_EncounteredError;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.Disposed += MediaPlayer_Disposed;
            });
        }
    }
    private void MediaPlayer_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("Media Player is disposed.");
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded -= MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.Opening -= MediaPlayer_Opening;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.EndReached -= MediaPlayer_EndReached;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.EncounteredError -= MediaPlayer_EncounteredError;
                VlcObject.MediaPlayer.Disposed -= MediaPlayer_Disposed;
                //VlcObject = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Error while disposing MediaPlayer: ");
                Logger.LogError(ex);
            }
        });
    }
    public void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter, bool isBack = false)
    {            
            InitializeVLC();
    }
```

Here is the exception I get:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject
>   newParent)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object
>   oldContent, Object newContent)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)    at
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object
>   instance, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member,
>   Object obj, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst,
>   XamlMember property, Object value)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
>   IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream,
>   ParserContext pc)    at
>   MS.Internal.AppModel.AppModelKnownContentFactory.BamlConverter(Stream
>   stream, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean
>   sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean
>   isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)    at
>   MS.Internal.AppModel.MimeObjectFactory.GetObjectAndCloseStream(Stream
>   s, ContentType contentType, Uri baseUri, Boolean
>   canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean
>   allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader&
>   asyncObjectConverter)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.GetObjectFromResponse(WebRequest
>   request, WebResponse response, Uri destinationUri, Object navState)
>   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.DoNavigate(Uri source,
>   NavigationMode f, Object navState)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigateQueueItem.Dispatch(Object obj)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Can some one please help me.

Comment: What is `VlcObject` ?

Answer (score 0):

The "Disconnect it first." part of the error message is key here. Since you are binding the content, it sounds like the same binding is active on another control (or page). You should try to ensure that the content is not bound to more than one control. Do the pages share the same view model? You could try to have a unique view model for each page with a unique content wrapper for each view model.

Comment: The VlcObject is bound to only one control i.e., ContentControl and also I have only one view bound to thisViewModel. The VlcObject is an instance of Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl and I have noticed that VlcObject.MediaPlayer is being disposed on navigating to the second page. So on navigating to videos page, I am creating a new instance of VlcObject.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below given links are addressing the same issue. Go thru once you might get a hint.

[Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026605/specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it)

[Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109738/specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it)